# What is $\operatorname{Hom}(S,Q^\vee)$ for a Grassmannian?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, grassmannian, tangent-bundle

Let $G(k,V)$ be the Grassmannian of $k$-planes in a complex vector space $V$ of dimension $n$. There is the famous universal exact sequence of vector bundles on $G(k,V)$
$$
0 \to S \to V \otimes \mathcal O \to Q \to 0.
$$
Moreover, one can define the tangent bundle $T_{G(k,V)}=\operatorname{Hom}(S,Q)$.

Explicitly, what can we say about $\operatorname{Hom}(S,Q^\vee)$?

Comment: You have a typo. $\mathrm{Hom}(Q^\vee, S^\vee)$ is the same thing as $\mathrm{Hom}(S, Q)$, a.k.a. $S^\vee \otimes Q$, it is not dual to it. The dual is $\mathrm{Hom}(Q, S)$, a.k.a. $S \otimes Q^\vee$.

Comment: @JakeLevinson you totally right! Thanks